# Switching to activity created using DroiGap

Tags: android, cordova

I have an activity in android and another activity created using Phonegap extending DroidGap.

I want to switch from the MainActivity to the activity created using PhoneGap.

Is it Possible to do that?

```
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:             com.krishnan.kuruk.MapActivity
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at com.krishnan.kuruk.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:107)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-23 18:00:35.249: E/AndroidRuntime(24937):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya.. It's possible.. I think u havent declared both classes **MainActivity** and **PhoneGapActivity** in ur manifest..

Comment: Thanks sir :) I have resolved the problem using WebView class of Android